# Find the sequence according to values of a column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I’m developing a website using PHP. I have connected it to a mySQL database. The database has a table called ‘student’ and it has two columns as ‘marks’ and ‘place. It is as follows.

```
Marks | place
------|-------
70    |
90    |
80    |
50    |
```

I want to fill the ‘place’ columns as follows. (The place for the highest marks should be 1, The place for the second highest marks should be 2, etc)

```
Marks | place
------|-------
70    | 3
90    | 1
80    | 2
50    | 4
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty simple to do - What code do you have so far?

Comment: Basically you could read the table results in "Marks" descending order in a loop, storing them in an array, read them incrementing a counter and issue an update query for each result acordingly.

Comment: @Calimero, Can you please give me a the code?

Comment: I could but you wouldn't learn anything in the process - I suggest you either post your existing code or search for examples of the individual steps I provided above and try to assemble them together. No big deal !

Comment: @Calimero, this is my code so far. I have reset the ‘place’ column as zero. I have no idea of updating the place column as 1,2,3,4 according to marks. 
$marks = [];
$m = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY marks");
while ($d = mysql_fetch_assoc($m)) $marks[] = $d;
mysql_query("UPDATE student SET place=0");

Comment: you are on the right track, however as I said you might want to get your results in an array first, then loop (again) over that array to perform your UPDATE queries since the mysql driver will not approve issuing queries while browsing the resultset of another query. Please consider editing your question as well.

Comment: @Calimero, Sorry, I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: first : loop over the results of your select to get the results in an array (nothing more). then, perform another loop over this array to issue your update queries (incrementing a counter as you go and using its value in the queries).

Comment: Why to do it using PHP if you can simply achieve it using MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
SET @i := 0;
UPDATE `table_name` SET place = (SELECT @i := @i+1) ORDER BY Marks desc
```